# angular-Gantt table : custom header

Tags: angularjs, gantt-chart, angular-gantt

I'm creating an angular-gantt table, and I would like to change columns headers.
I saw the attributes *columns* and *headers* in the plugin **Table** but I don't understand how to use these.

You can see my gantt chart here :

[image: I have this gantt chart, and I need to change "Name"]

I need to change the *Name* label and I tried some things :

**controller.ts**

```
this.options = {
                data: [],
                viewScale: 'hour',
                headers: ['day', 'hour'],
                tableHeader: {
                    'model.name': 'jour'
                },
                headersFormats: {
                    day: 'dddd',
                    hour: 'HH:mm'
                },
                sortMode: 'name',
                columns: ['jour'],
            }
```

**View.html**

```
<div gantt data="employeeviewctrl.ganttData"
                     headers="employeeviewctrl.options.headers"
                     headers-formats="employeeviewctrl.options.headersFormats"
                     sort-mode="employeeviewctrl.options.sortMode"
                     columns=[model.jour]>
                    <gantt-table enabled="true"
                                 headers="employeeviewctrl.options.headerTable">
                    </gantt-table>
                    <gantt-tooltips enabled="true">
                    </gantt-tooltips>
 </div>
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

**controller:**

```
columnsHeaders: { 'model.name': 'Jour' }
```

**html :**

```
<gantt-table enabled="true"                               
    headers="columnsHeaders">
</gantt-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just made a typo... I have mine set to an empty string so if it's not the typo, then I can still help.

**controller**

```
headerTable
```

**html**

```
tableHeader
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found the problem. You can look at the answer I posted :)